# MySQL Datediff skip saturday and sunday

Tags: php, mysql, datediff

I need to get the total count of rows where in the difference of the end date and start date is less than or equal to 2. But i need to skip saturdays and sundays if for example my start date is 11-29-2012 and the end date is 12-03-2012 i should be getting a difference of 2 rather than 4 because 12-1-2012 is sat and 12-2-2012 is sunday.

DateE is the start date
ReplayDate is the end date

```
SELECT  
   DATE_FORMAT(DateE, '%Y-%m-%d') AS startdate,
   DATE_FORMAT(ReplyDate, '%Y-%m-%d') AS replydate,   
   DATEDIFF(ReplyDate,DateE) as diff
FROM emailtodb.emailtodb_email 
WHERE 
   Status = 2  
AND
   DATEDIFF(ReplyDate,DateE)<=2
AND 
   DATE_FORMAT(DateE, '%Y-%m-%d') 
BETWEEN 
   '2012-11-29' AND '2012-12-12'  
AND 
   TIME_FORMAT(DateE, '%H:%i:00') 
BETWEEN 
   '00:00' AND '23:59'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check it in the php script. When you have fetched the startDate and endDate and dateDifference then check

```
$startDay = date('l', $startDate);
$endDay = date('l', $endDate);

if ($dateDifference < 4){
     if ( $startDay == 'Saturday' || $startDay == 'Sunday' ){
        $dateDifference--;
     }
     if ( $endDay == 'Saturday' || $endDay == 'Sunday' ){
        $dateDifference--;
     }
 }
 else{
    $totalWeek = (int) $dateDifference / 7;
    $dateDifference -= ($totalWeek + 1)*2;

    if ($startDay == 'Saturday' && $endDay = 'Saturday')
        $dateDifference++;
    else if ($startDay == 'Sunday' && $endDay = 'Sunday')
        $dateDifference++;
    else
    {
         if($endDate == 'Saturday')
             $dateDifference++;
        if ($startDay == 'Sunday')
            $dateDifference++;
    }   
 }
```

I haven't compiled the code but i hope it will work

Comment: i cant do this in our code mainly the exact query has a group by date at the end. so meaning for example 2012-12-12 has 4 results that has a  date difference of <=2 excluding weekends. so i need to do it in the query.

Comment: so you need to do this in your query only

Comment: you can create your procedure or function in your mysql server to calculate date difference [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html]

Comment: yes i need to do it in my query only. 
is there anyway i can do it without making any function in my sql server?